# const fns are an unstable feature when using AtomicUsize::new

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, atomic

What is wrong with this code?

```
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

static mut counter: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);

fn main() {}
```

I get this error:

```
error: const fns are an unstable feature
 --> src/main.rs:3:35
  |>
3 |> static mut counter: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);
  |>                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: in Nightly builds, add `#![feature(const_fn)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

The docs mention that other atomic int sizes are unstable, but `AtomicUsize` is apparently stable.

The purpose of this is to get an atomic per-process counter.

Comment: The atomic doesn't need to and should not be in a `static mut`, it should be in a plain `static`. Atomic operations use interior mutability when modifying them. You see that all their mutating methods use `&self` as the first argument (a shared reference).

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, because they don't need to rely on the borrow checker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you cannot call functions outside of a function as of Rust 1.10. That requires a feature that is not yet stable: constant function evaluation.

You can initialize an atomic variable to zero using [`ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/constant.ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT.html) (or the appropriate variant):

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT};

static COUNTER: AtomicUsize = ATOMIC_USIZE_INIT;

fn main() {}
```

As [bluss points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452284/const-fns-are-an-unstable-feature-when-using-atomicusizenew/39452377#comment66234307_39452284), there's no need to make this mutable. And as the compiler points out, `static` and `const` values should be in `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`.