# Is it possible to write a const function that folds over an iterator?

Tags: rust, constants

Is it possible to write a const function that folds over an iterator? When I try:

```
const fn foo(s: &str) -> u64 {
    return s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| -> u64 {
        return accumulator ^ (char as u64);
    });
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error: function pointers in const fn are unstable
 --> src/lib.rs:2:30
  |
2 |       return s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| -> u64 {
  |  ______________________________^
3 | |         return accumulator ^ (char as u64);
4 | |     });
  | |_____^
```

I presume that my anonymous function `|x, y| -> x { ... }` is passed as a function pointer to `fold()` and that's what's causing the error.

Is there some kind of const lambda that I can pass to `fold` here, or can I just use a for loop instead and accumulate the result in a mutable variable which I then return from the `foo` function? I have absolutely no Rust experience...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in stable Rust 1.59. You will need to make your function non-const:

```
fn foo(s: &str) -> u64 {
    s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| {
        accumulator ^ (char as u64)
    })
}
```

Note I removed the explicit `return` keywords and closure return type to be idiomatic.

See also:

- [const fns are an unstable feature when using AtomicUsize::new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39452284/155423)
- [Why can't I use a function returning a compile-time constant as a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29250386/155423)
- [Is it possible to have a recursive function computed at compile-time in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44448488/155423)

---

If you attempt this in nightly Rust:

```
const fn foo(s: &str) -> u64 {
    s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| {
        accumulator ^ (char as u64)
    })
}
```

You'll get a different error:

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `core::str::<impl str>::chars` in constant functions
 --> src/lib.rs:2:7
  |
2 |     s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| {
  |       ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants

error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `<Chars as Iterator>::fold::<u64, [closure@src/lib.rs:2:23: 4:6]>` in constant functions
 --> src/lib.rs:2:15
  |
2 |       s.chars().fold(0, |accumulator, char| {
  |  _______________^
3 | |         accumulator ^ (char as u64)
4 | |     })
  | |______^
  |
  = note: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

Calling `Iterator::fold` requires several extensions to [the original `const fn` RFC 911](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md) to be implemented. For example, it's expressly forbidden by the original RFC:

> Traits, trait implementations and their methods cannot be `const`

Since closures are implemented as generics backed by traits, I don't immediately see that they could be easily implemented for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough edits. Do you know if there's a proposed solution to let us use higher-order functions inside const functions in the future? I looked at the RFC thread linked from the last question you linked but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Would be nice if `no` wasn't still the answer.

Comment: @Squirrel wishing won't change it ‍♀️. You can attempt to help implement the required changes to the Rust compiler to help get it closer.

Answer (score 2):

For somebody who struggled with this – for now you can still use the plain `loop` or `while` in const fn expressions.